# Edit Security Settings with GPEdit after leaving Domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

With an old company laptop on Windows 10, I removed its association to the Active Directory Domain with a local Administrator account.

But, I am finding that I cannot edit any Policies in the Security Settings area of the Local Security Policy, either via `selpol.msc` or `gpedit.msc`. I can open the individual Policy, but the controls are disabled. I can edit other Policies outside of the Security Settings, so I am trying to determine what is preventing me from editing those particular policies and how to enable the editing of those values once again.

Thoughts I have considered:

- Did the PC not fully leave the domain and consequently, does it still possess some Domain Group Policy settings somewhere?
- Does Windows support some feature of ironclad Security Policies that someone can slipstream into an installation?

Comment: Why would you not just install a fresh copy of Windows?

Comment: @joeqwerty: I could and I might. But, I still have interest to know what put the PC into this state.